# How to keep application session alive in selenium

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, testng

I have browsed through internet but did not get any appropriate solution.
My query here is, my selenium script takes long time to execute as application is large, cause of which session of application is getting expired and it logout form the application. I have tried tried with the following javascript code in @BeforeMethod in testng but still no luck,

```
public void keepSessionAlive()
{
    ((JavascriptExecutor)Driver.driver).executeScript("checkActivity(1200000, 60000, 0);"+

                "function checkActivity(timeout, interval, elapsed) "
                + "{"+
                    "if ($.active) "
                    + "{"+
                            "elapsed = 0;"+
                            "$.active = false;"+
                            "$.get('app/heartbeat');"
                    + "}"+
                "if (elapsed < timeout) "
                + "{"+
                        "elapsed += interval;"+
                        "setTimeout(function() "
                        + "{"+
                            "checkActivity(timeout, interval, elapsed);"+
                            "}, "
                        + "interval);"+
                "} "
                + "else "
                + "{"+
                        "window.location = 'timeout';"+
                    "}"+
                "};");
    }
```

Comment: Did you also add something to your application that would respond to `app/heartbeat` requests, and the refreshes the session timeout on each request?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/heartbeat", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  request.getSession();
 }